# Storing Data in Session/ViewData

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc-4

So I have Edit function in my site. Now edit is working perfectly. I just want to store the edited data in `Session` and pass it to view on refresh.

When i click on done HTTPPOST is called. Now i want to save edited data and show it back on Done click. Thanks

Comment: you want save in session at the end of Movies(string actiontype) and get this value in the second method?

Comment: Yea correct , that is what i want.:)

Answer (score 3):

you can use

```
HttpContext.Current.Session("MOVIES") = model
```

for save and

```
HttpContext.Current.Session("MOVIES")
```

for get.

however before you have to enable session adding this two class

```
 public class SessionStateRouteHandler : IRouteHandler 
{ 
    IHttpHandler IRouteHandler.GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        return new SessionableControllerHandler(requestContext.RouteData);
    }
}

 public class SessionableControllerHandler : HttpControllerHandler, IRequiresSessionState
 {
     public SessionableControllerHandler(RouteData routeData)
         : base(routeData)
     { }
 }
```

and register the route as

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApi", "api/{controller}/{action}/").RouteHandler = new SessionStateRouteHandler();
```

that's enable session in web api.

Comment: Why does HttpContext.Current.Session show error on current,do i need to add reference for it??

Comment: System.Web.HttpContextBase does not contain a definiton for "Current"

Comment: try with System.Web.HttpContext.Current if you are using MVC